# react, nextJs, toggling Navbar with states

Tags: reactjs, scroll, next.js

I am trying to toggle my navbar depending on if I am below a certain point on the page.
I also only want my navbar to be showing on that part of the page if I am `scrolling up` (meaning once I scroll down, even if I am in that part of the page, my navbar will un-toggle until I scroll up again).

I can't seem to get the logic down and not sure if I'm even doing this the right way.
I am using an external library (react-use-scroll-direction) that detects scroll direction.

**Problem**:
When I start scrolling up, it keeps flickering back between "open" and "close" each time I scroll up in that part of the page.

```
import { useScrollDirection } from 'react-use-scroll-direction'

  const {
    isScrolling,
    isScrollingX,
    isScrollingY,
    isScrollingUp,
    isScrollingDown,
    isScrollingLeft,
    isScrollingRight,
    scrollDirection,
  } = useScrollDirection()

  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const navHeight = ref.current?.clientHeight;
    if (window.scrollY > navHeight) {

      if (isScrollingUp && setOpen(!isOpen)) {
        setOpen(isOpen);
        console.log('Open!');
      }
      else {
        console.log('Not Open');
      }

    }

  });


<div ref={ref} className={isOpen ? styles.open: styles.close} >
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to apply the `position: fixed` to the navbar when scroll position reach in a specific point on the screen, take a look:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useScrollDirection } from "react-use-scroll-direction";
export default function App() {
  const { isScrollingUp, isScrollingDown } = useScrollDirection();

  const navRef = useRef(null);
  // add fixed class if is scrolling up
  useEffect(() => {
    // 600 refers to the point on the screen
    // where the navbar should appears
    if (window.scrollY < 600 && isScrollingUp) {
      navRef.current.classList.add("fixed");
    }
  }, [isScrollingUp]);

  // remove the class if is scrolling down
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isScrollingDown) {
      navRef.current.classList.remove("fixed");
    }
  }, [isScrollingDown]);

  return (
    <div className={"main"}>
      <div ref={navRef} className={"open"} />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the css class:

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

See the [complete working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-violet-ezis4q?file=/src/App.js)